# Ошибка в условии javasvript

Tags: javascript, ember.js, if

```
Код:
 $.getJSON(url,function(data){
                me.set('content', []);
                $(data.items).each(function(){                    
                    var t = App.Tweet.create({                                       
                        screen_name: this.actor.displayName,        
                        create_post: this.published,
                        author_link: this.actor.url,
                        author_picture: this.actor.image.url,
                        url_post: this.url,
                        author_name: this.actor.displayName,                                                                        
                        social_network: 'google',
                        link_post: this.url                 
                        if(this.verb === "share"){                                                  
                            if(this.object.content === ""){                                
                                $(this.object.attachments).each(function(){
                                    share = this;                                    
                                    attachment_post: '<img src="' + share.image.url + '"/>',
                                });                                
                            }                          
                        }   
                    });
                    me.pushObject(t);
                })
            });
```

пишет ошибку SyntaxError: missing } after property list if(this.verb === "share")

в чем дело не пойму.

Comment: а что тут непонятного? if(this.verb === "share") внутри декларации объекта стоит.

Comment: можно подробней, как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А еще лучше вот так. Тогда код более читабельный:

```
 $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

        me.set('content', []);

        function getAttachmentPost(_o) {

            var result = '';

            if (_o.verb === "share" && _o.object.content === "") {
                $(_o.object.attachments).each(function () {
                    result = '<img src="' + this.image.url + '"/>';
                    return false;
                });
            }

            return result;
        }

        $(data.items).each(function () {
            var t = App.Tweet.create({
                screen_name: this.actor.displayName,
                create_post: this.published,
                author_link: this.actor.url,
                author_picture: this.actor.image.url,
                url_post: this.url,
                author_name: this.actor.displayName,
                social_network: 'google',
                link_post: this.url,
                attachment_post: getAttachmentPost(this)
            });

            me.pushObject(t);
        });
    });
```

Comment: но как теперь я  attachment_post помещу в объект t?

Comment: обратите внимание, что он уже в объекте. Функция getAttachmentPost() возвращает значение этого аттрибута.